# Cypress 'have.text' assertion coming up with doubled-up values

Tags: cypress, end-to-end

In testing an element's text content, the test seems to be finding doubled-up values of whatever the innerText actually is. For example, If I check if an element has the text content of "0" It should return true if this is the case. Instead, "00" is being returned.

**The Test Code**

```
describe('ProductCard add to cart increment count to 1', () => {
  it('should reveal corresponding Add to Cart buttons on hover and add to cart triggers an increase in cart count', () => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000');

    // Check if the cart badge exists and has an inner text of 0
    cy.get('[data-test="test-cart-badge"]').should('exist').and('have.text', '0');

    // Get the first ProductCard as an example
    cy.get('[data-test="product-card-test"]')
      .first()
      .invoke('show')
      .scrollIntoView()
      .invoke('attr', 'data-test-id')
      .then((productId) => {
        // Hover over the ProductCard
        cy.get(`[data-test="product-card-test"][data-test-id="${productId}"]`).first().trigger('mouseover');

        // Check if the corresponding Add to Cart buttons are visible
        cy.get(`[data-test="product-card-size-button-test"][data-test-id="${productId}"]`)
          .first()
          .click({ force: true });

        cy.get('[data-test="test-cart-badge"]').should('have.text', '1');
        cy.get('[data-test="test-cart-open-icon"]').click({ force: true });
        cy.get('[data-test="cart-plus-button-test"]').click({ force: true });
        cy.get('[data-test="test-cart-badge"]').should('have.text', '2');
        cy.get('[data-test="cart-minus-button-test"]').click({ force: true });
        cy.get('[data-test="test-cart-badge"]').should('have.text', '1');
        cy.get('[data-test="cart-minus-button-test"]').click({ force: true });
        cy.get('[data-test="test-cart-badge"]').should('have.text', '0');
      });
  });
});
```

**The Offending Lines**

`cy.get('[data-test="test-cart-badge"]').should('exist').and('have.text', '0');`

`cy.get('[data-test="test-cart-badge"]').should('have.text', '1');`

`cy.get('[data-test="test-cart-badge"]').should('have.text', '2');`

**The Element Being Tested**

```
<div class="mantine-Badge-root size-[1.3rem] mt-[0.25rem] mr-[0.25rem] mantine-15p6f3j" data-test="test-cart-badge">
  <span class="mantine-1t45alw mantine-Badge-inner">1</span>
</div>
```

**The First Assertion Error**

`Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '[ <div.mantine-Badge-root.size-[1.3rem].mt-[0.25rem].mr-[0.25rem].mantine-4r1tww>, 1 more... ]' to have text '0', but the text was '00'`

I've tried logging the actual value in the console and it is coming up correctly (eg it's coming up as 0 for the example provided in the first paragraph).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if there are multiple versions of an element on the page, the `cy.get()` query will pick up all of them and concatenate the text.

Try appending `.first()` filter or `:visible` qualifyer.

```js
cy.get('[data-test="test-cart-badge"]')
  .first()
  .should('have.text', '1')

cy.get('[data-test="test-cart-badge"]:visible')
  .should('have.text', '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the resolution to this issue. I didn't realise that when has.text is applied to an array of elements, it runs for each element in the array and outputs the result as a concatenated string of the text values for each element.

I remedied this by changing the code to:
`cy.get('[data-test="test-cart-badge"]').each(($elem) => expect($elem).to.have.text('2'));` (to use one line as an example)